# Cannot link css file with the correct url

Tags: html, css

I can't get my css file to be read correctly my the html page. Its something simple and related to the path.

This is what I currently have in the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

This is the domain

http://crea8tion.com/PU2/index.html

Can someone help me with the correct file path?

When i place the css file in the same location of the index.html file it works, but that isn't the ideal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public_html/Product Upload form/css/foundation.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`
Do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Product Upload form/css/foundation.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: @Dano007 these are your content files http://gyazo.com/7981143ce941b88bbcaa13a4801f64c4.png the last one is the one I pointed you need to change, just remove the /public_html part, can't you find that in the head of your page?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `public_html/` from your path.

You have:

```
/public_html/Product Upload form/css/foundation.css
```

Change to:

```
/Product Upload form/css/foundation.css
```

**Update:**

You also have JS errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://crea8tion.com/PU2/js/plupload.full.min.js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.plupload.queue.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pluploadQueue' index.html:131
```

Comment: See page source (or debugger window), you do have it. I see you changed it, and it's loading now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/PU2/css/foundation.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

`/`refers to the root. Your css file in in the `css` folder that is withing the `PU2` folder that is located at the root which is usually `public_html`.

You can access your stylesheet in a broswer here: http://crea8tion.com/PU2/css/foundation.css